# Error:(16, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, androidpdfviewer

i got that error 16,0 in pdf viewer when i try to open it in android studio https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

```
 buildscript {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
}
 }
 allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
 }
 android {
     compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
 }
```

Comment: You should try cloning the whole project and try running it. For starters, your compileSdk version is quite old

Comment: when i open and try new again i got this error "Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at two build.gradle file for a project with one module - one the project level and another the app level. Looks like you have mixed up both.

Move the android block to the app level build.gradle file and also don't forget to include minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion

Comment: can u give me sample code, i'm newbie on this

Comment: The sample code is in the GitHub URL that you've posted in the question. You can see project level gradle file in the root level and app level file in the directory android-pdf-viewer

Comment: thank you it's work when i used same sdk with the project